# How to get on-the-fly instrumentation with JaCoCo on a running java app

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, instrumentation, on-the-fly

I am trying to identify which classes and, if possible methods, are used by a running java app.

In the JaCoCo Coverage Analysis Diagram at https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/implementation.html they mention the On-the-fly instrumentation available via their Java Agent.

I am fairly new to java and I was able to add the maven plugin to the project but I am confused as to what I am supposed to do now. I assume I somehow need to run this and pass the process id of the running app and then use the "file system" or "tcp" options to retrieve the used classes/methods captured.

Any details/explanations will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you don't even necessarily need on-the-fly instrumentation. Why do you think that you do?

Comment: Do you want to get coverage of the normal execution of your program? From what I understand maven plugin only calculates coverage of test executions.

Comment: @Michael I need it for applications that are in production, are there any other options?

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu from what I could understand using the plugin only abstracts some of the settings, I did not know it works only for test executions. What should I use for on-the-fly code coverage?

Comment: @CristianG You shouldn't run coverage against production code.

Comment: @Michael my bad, we have some scenarios and we want to run coverage against them, not in production.

Comment: How do you execute the application? Maven? with Java?

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu as far as I know is Maven, but I might be mistaken. Does it make a difference?

Comment: The way to activate the Jacoco agent will vary depending on how you execute your program.

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu how would I do it for Maven? Can I configure it somehow or pass some arguments? I would also prefer the tcp version.